# copy everything before the first blank line

Tags: perl, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a file with several blocks of text separated by blank line. Ex.:

```
block1
block1

block2

block3
block3
```

I need a solution with sed, awk or Perl to locate the first blank line and redirect the previous block to another file and so on until the end of the file.

I have this command in sed that locates the first block, but not the rest:

```
sed -e '/./!Q'
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What should be filename of the output file.

Answer (score 4):

give this line a try:

```
awk -v RS=""  '{print > "file"++c".txt"}' input
```

it will generate `file1...n.txt`

Comment: this option seems more compact.

Comment: That's the better way

Answer (score 1):

Here's an `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{file="file"++cont}/^$/{file="file"++cont;next}{print>file}' infile
```

**Results**

```
$ cat file1 
block1
block1
$ cat file2
block2
$ cat file3
block3
block3
```

Answer (score 1):

taking into account several empty string between block

```
awk '/./{if(!L)++C;print>"Out"C".txt"}{L=$0!~/^$/}' YourFile
```

Sed will not allow different external files (*unspecified number of* in fact) as output

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution in Perl

```
open( my $fh, '<', '/tmp/a.txt' ) or die $!;

{
    ## record delimiter
    local $/ = "\n\n";
    my $count = 1;

    while ( chomp( my $block = <$fh> ) ) {
        open( my $ofh, '>', sprintf( '/tmp/file%d', $count++ ) ) or die $!;
        print {$ofh} $block;
        close($ofh);
    }

}

close($fh);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $n     = 0;
my $block = '';
while (<DATA>) {    # line gets stored in $_
    if (/^\s*$/) {    # blank line
        write_to_file( 'file' . ++$n, $block );
        $block = '';
    } else {
        $block .= $_;
    }
}

# Write any remaining lines
write_to_file( 'file' . ++$n, $block );

sub write_to_file {
    my $file = shift;
    my $data = shift;

    open my $fh, '>', $file or die $!;
    print $fh $data;
    close $fh;
}

__DATA__
block1
block1

block2

block3
block3
```

Output:

```
$ grep . file*
file1:block1
file1:block1
file2:block2
file3:block3
file3:block3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# store all lines in $data
my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my @blocks = split /\n\n/, $data;

my $n = 0;
write_to_file( 'file' . ++$n, $_ ) for @blocks;

sub write_to_file {
    my $file = shift;
    my $data = shift;

    open my $fh, '>', $file or die $!;
    print $fh $data;
    close $fh;
}

__DATA__
block1
block1

block2

block3
block3
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU csplit & sed):

```
csplit -qf uniqueFileName file '/^$/' '{*}' && sed -i '/^$/d' uniqueFileName*
```

or if you want to go with the defaults:

```
csplit -q file '/^$/' '{*}' && sed -i '/^$/d' xx*
```

Use:

```
tail -n+1 xx* # to check the results
```